# Show that the sequence defined as $x_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{x_n}$ converges and calculate it's limit (proof check)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, solution-verification

Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined as $x_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{x_n},x_0=1$ converges and calculate it's limit

Probably there are already posts concerning this sequence, but i would like to have a feedback on my proof, please. My attempt is to show that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

First, we have $\forall p\ge1$ that:

$|x_p-x_{p-1}|=\Big|\dfrac{x_{p-2}-x_{p-1}}{\underbrace{x_{p-1}\cdot x_{p-2}}_{>2}}\Big| \le\frac{1}{2}|x_{p-1}-x_{p-2}|=...=(\frac{1}{2})^{p-1}|x_1-x_0|=(\frac{1}{2})^{p-1}$

Then we want to show that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. By definition we must have: $\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists N \ \forall m,n\ge N \ (m>n)$:

$|x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon$.

But,

$|x_m-x_n|\le |x_m-x_{m-1}|+|x_{m-1}-x_{m-2}|+...+|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le (\frac{1}{2})^{m-1}+(\frac{1}{2})^{m-2}+...+(\frac{1}{2})^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(\frac{1}{2})^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac{1}{2})^k=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}<\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

So, one can chose $N$, such that $\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}<\varepsilon$ to satisfy Cauchy sequence definition.  So, $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and so convergent.

$\bullet$Limit calculation:

We can write that: $x_n=(x_n-x_{n-1})+(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})+...+(x_1+x_0)+x_0$ and that $\forall n\ge1$: $x_n-x_{n-1}\le (-\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$

Therefore:

$x_n\le 1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k=\frac{1+(\frac{1}{2})^n}{1+\frac{1}{2}}+1$

So, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\frac{5}{3}$. We conclude then that $(x_n)$ converges to $\frac{5}{3}$

Edit: I noticed that my limit calculation is wrong as i bound $(x_n)$ instead of "calculating" it directly.

So, to calculate the exact limit value i would pass by the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n+1}$ and then solve an equation $L^2-L-1=0$ (where $L$ denotes sequence's limit as it goes to infinity) and conclude that it's limit is equal to $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$(golden ratio). (Of course by proving before that, that $(x_n)>0$ by induction)

Comment: If the sequence converges to some $L \ne 0$, it must satisfy $L = 1+\frac 1L$. So, your final answer is wrong and, in fact, you need to say something about $x_0$ in order to choose one of the possible limits.

Comment: @PierreCarre I edited my answer. Is it correct what i added?
Edit: I set wrong equation...

Comment: The limit is not $\frac 53$. For most $x_0$ the limit is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$... But, for some, the sequence may not be well defined (e.g. $x_0 = -\frac 12$)... and for others it may converge to another value (e.g. $x_0 = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{3}$)

Comment: I'm sorry for so many edits, but i forgot to precise the $x_0$ value in my question...

Comment: In that case the limit is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Your upper bound on $x_n$ (at the end of your post) just provides an upper bound for the limit, not the limit itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have established that the sequence converges (it's Cauchy), you know that the limit, say $L$, must satisfy $L = 1+\frac 1L$, simply because $\lim x_n = \lim x_{n+1}$. So, we narrow the possibilities to $L = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Since you can easily prove that if $x_0=1$ the sequence remains positive, you conclude that the limit is $L = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: Right, thank you! Is my proof that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy correct?

Comment: Yes, that part is ok.